# Call Number (CordovaCallNumberPlugin) not work on ios 12

Tags: ios, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

[CordovaCallNumberPlugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/call-number/)
it working fine in android 7 and ios 11  but not working in ios 12 some  time not installed plugin error ms and after use isCallSupported() **
this.callNumberPlugin.isCallSupported()**
Error launching dialer NoFeatureCallSupported
WARN: Install the CallNumber  plugin: 'ionic Cordova plugin add call-number

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.1, (and 14 other plugins)

System:

ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v11.4.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.4.1
   OS         : macOS
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Comment: This is more a workaround than a solution, but to avoid using this plugin, you can trigger a confirmation alert for a phone call in HTML, this way : `<a href="tel:5551234567">Call (555)123-4567</a>`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ios platform and re-downloading it? I was having issues when I first downloaded the call-number plugin and re-downloading the ios platform fixed it.